# Discussion in CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am having a CSV file with three columns as below and I want to count the value of 'AT' and both 'AT + LH' for each Type and Date, then put it in a separate column in another CSV file.

**Input CSV file:**

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Date  ║ Type  ║ Value ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ Nov-2 ║ M2222 ║ AT    ║
║ Nov-2 ║ M2222 ║ LH    ║
║ Nov-3 ║ M2222 ║ LH    ║
║ Nov-3 ║ M2223 ║ LH    ║
║ Nov-3 ║ M2223 ║ AT    ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I need the output like this:

**Output CSV file:**

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Date  ║ Type  ║ Total (Total = AT + LH) ║ Value of AT ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Nov-2 ║ M2222 ║                       2 ║           1 ║
║ Nov-3 ║ M2222 ║                       1 ║           0 ║
║ Nov-3 ║ M2223 ║                       2 ║           1 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I have tried using dictionaries for this and am unable to get the desired output. But in the output I am getting the columns of Date and Type into a single column.

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections
import pandas as pd

with open(r'file1','wb') as crack,open(r'file2','wb') as crack1:

  w = csv.writer(crack,delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
  w1 = csv.writer(crack1,delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

  for row in zip(['DATE & BASIC TYPE'],['Total Triggerred']):
    w.writerow(row)

  for row in zip(['DATE & BASIC TYPE'],['No of LOH']):
   w1.writerow(row)

 with open(r'inputfile, 'rb') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  next(reader, None)
  dict1=defaultdict(list)

  for row in reader:
   dict1[(row[0],row[1])].append(int(row[3]))

  for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
   for row in zip([key], [sum(dict1[key])]):
    #print key, sum(dict1[key])
      w.writerow(row)

 with open(r'inputfile', 'rb') as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)
   next(reader, None)
   dict2=defaultdict(list)

 for row in reader:
   if row[2]=='AUTO RELEASE':
      dict2[(row[0],row[1])].append(int(row[3]))

 for key, value in dict2.iteritems():
   for row in zip([key], [sum(dict2[key])]):
    #print key, sum(dict2[key])
     w1.writerow(row)

 a = pd.read_csv(r'file1.csv')
 b = pd.read_csv(r'file2.csv')
 merged = a.merge(b, on='DATE & BASIC TYPE')
 merged.to_csv(r'outputfile.csv', index=False)
```

I am getting Output like this:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════╦═════════════╗
║    Date & Type    ║ Total ║ Value of AT ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════╬═════════════╣
║ ('Nov-2','M2222') ║     2 ║           1 ║
║ ('Nov-3','M2222') ║     1 ║           0 ║
║ ('Nov-3','M2223') ║     2 ║           1 ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input_csv.csv', sep=';')
print df.groupby(['Date','Type'])['Type','Value'].count()
```

---

Here's the additional code that Albe originally submitted in the comments.

```
import pandas as pd

#read csv file using data frame 
df = pd.read_csv('input_csv.csv', sep=',')

#count how many "AT" values in a data frame 
df['Value AT'] = (df['Value'] == 'AT').astype(int)

#sum "AT" and "LH" of a data frame
df['TOT'] = (df['Value'] == 'AT').astype(int) + (df['Value'] == 'LH').astype(int)

#grouping by data and type 
print df.groupby(['Date', 'Type'])['TOT', 'Value AT'].sum()
```

...At the end you can add this piece of code to create the csv output file:

```
#print df_grouped 
df_grouped.to_csv(r'outputfile.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but am getting same value for 'Value of AT' and 'Total'.

Comment: @Sivaraman: Ok I've understand:
Try this code with explaination in a comment:
`import pandas as pd`
`#read csv file using data frame`
`df = pd.read_csv('input_csv.csv',sep=',')`
`#count how many "AT" values in a data frame`
`df['Value AT'] = (df['Value'] == 'AT').astype(int)`
`#sum  "AT" and "LH" of a data frame`
`df['TOT'] = (df['Value'] == 'AT').astype(int) + (df['Value'] == 'LH').astype(int)`
`#grouping by data and type`
`print df.groupby(['Date','Type'])['TOT','Value AT'].sum()`
Now you can write the output in a new csv file.

Comment: ...At the end you can add this piece of code to create csv output file:

`#print df_grouped
df_grouped.to_csv(r'outputfile.csv', index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating the task. It is much simplier to use T-SQL in such situation. For instance you can use MySQL, create table for the CSV file, load data into it using this approach: [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Then select aggregated data you need using query like this:

```
SELECT 
t.Date,
t.Type,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table as t1
    WHERE t1.Date = t.Date and t1.Type = t.Type and t1.Value IN ('AT', 'LH')
) as `Total (Total = AT + LH)`,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table as t2
    WHERE t2.Date = t.Date and t2.Type = t.Type and t2.Value IN ('AT')
) as `Value of AT`
FROM table as t
GROUP BY t.Data, t.Type;
```

And load data back to CSV: [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know MySQL and is there some other way to do this in python.

Comment: Is it possible to do it dictionary using multiple keys.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, how to do it in python instead of MySQL.